# UIImagePickerController does not present when triggered from delegate function

Tags: ios, swift

I have one weird case where UIImagePickerController will not present.

**Context:** I'm using UIImagePicker to let a user pick a profile image from their photos. They tap to add a profile image and initially a modal is triggered where they can pick between using their local photos and their facebook profile photo.

This modal delegates back to the profile view controller where all the functions below exist. The modal fires `didSelectProfilePhotoOption` - in this case with .fromPhotos.

```
func didSelectProfilePhotoOption(photoSource: PhotoSource) {
    switch photoSource {
    case .fromFacebook:
        useFacebookPhotoForProfile()
    case .fromPhotos:
        selectProfileImageFromPhotoLibrary()
    }
}
```

This is important, because I have tried just triggering `selectProfileImageFromPhotoLibrary` from the view controller (rather than the modal delegate) and the UIImagePickerController shows every time.

```
func selectProfileImageFromPhotoLibrary() {
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    handleImageAuthStatus(status: status)
}

func handleImageAuthStatus(status: PHAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .authorized:
        presentImagePicker()
    case .denied:
        //show an error message
    case .notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization( { status in
            self.handleImageAuthStatus(status: status)
        })
    case .restricted:
        //show an error message   
    }
}

func presentImagePicker() {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The added weirdness is that UIImagePickerController will show when it's chained as part of requesting the photo permissions.

So in the case:

`didSelectProfilePhotoOption(photoSource: .fromPhotos)` **>>>** `selectProfileImageFromPhotoLibrary` **>>>** `handleImageAuthStatus(status: .notDetermined)` **>>>** (grant permissions) **>>>** `handleImageAuthStatus(status: .authorized)`

...UIImagePickerController shows every time.

Any ideas what's going on here? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying you have a view controller visible and you delegate back to a previous view controller that is no longer visible because I don't think you can present on that previous one in that case.  Do you get any warnings in the console?

Comment: "Are you saying you have a view controller visible and you delegate back to a previous view controller that is no longer visible" - that's correct, though the modal view controller does close at the same time the delegate fires. I've seen this UI pattern in other apps, would you recommend just triggering the image picker directly from the modal then?...No console warnings.

Comment: So based on your comment, I tried dismissing the modal and then calling the delegate (before it called the delegate and then closed itself on the next line). This seems to work.

Comment: Sorry I was asleep and couldn't reply sooner.  Glad you've got it working how you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help!